# How to build a web page that checks if my routers web interface is accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

In my house I have plenty of routers and access points (about 7 + a printer).
They all have web interface that i can browse to. (Ex "http://192.168.1.1")

Sometime they go bad and needs to be restarted.

I wanted to create an html file, that will act as a Dashboard , that will show me the list of routers and whether  they are "Ok" or "Error".

I don't know exactly how to do it.
I've tried 2 methods:

1. Use $.ajax, but Ajax has "Same origin policy" so that won't go. (Or I can do some stuff with a server, but I don't want to run a server just for that).
2. I tried loading an image from a certain router web interface, and check if its available
   that actually worked, but only for the web interfaces that didn't require a login upfront. For those it asked for my login, and I want a dashboard where I don't have to answer to any prompts. Just "Ok" or "Error".

   ```
   <img src="image.jpg" />
   <div>displayed after the image is loaded</div>

   <script>
       $('img').load(function() {
           $('div').show();
      });
   </script>
   ```

   [taken from here](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/08/05/jquery-check-whether-image-is-loaded/)

Is there a way I can achieve it? Something like "ping" a web interface to see if it's there or not..

Thanks for the help

Comment: 7 routers? in a single house? uh.... why?

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need a server for this to be easy. Just a `ping` or `curl` maybe.

Comment: (If you must know..) I'v linked all of my friends that live in the same building with me, we are renting all of the apatments in the building..

Comment: You wouldn't have to run a server, just a simple script would suffice. As far as I know pinging isn't possible via JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe check out this plugin: http://binarykitten.com/js/88-jquery-plugin-ajax-head-request.html

Make a request and see if the response is code 200.

Comment: Thenks for the help, but it did not work. The link is talking basically about ajax, insted of POST/GET it uses HEAD. but still "Same origin policy" problem.

Comment: Well, I suppose I'd go with cURL then, considering you can't avoid the same origin policy. This should be a pretty easy script to build with PHP and you can install a local LAMP server (XAMPP, MAMP..). If you are interested in this approach, I would be more than glad to help you out with the script.

Comment: One crazy idea popped in mind - would it help if you created an HTML page with a list of iframes? You could do something like: `<h2>192.168.1.1</h2>` and under that one, add an iframe pointing to that location. That way, if a router is not OK, it will show an error inside the iframe.

Comment: I can do that, but the problem will be, that when I'll load the page I'll get a prompt (7 of them) asking me for user/pass.
I want to create a page without any prompts.

Comment: hmm.. is there a way to "Auto Fail" the authentication prompt of the router's web interface?

Comment: Maybe try adding some JS in the onload event of the iframe. I'm just shooting in the dark at the moment :) `<iframe onload="someJSfunctionToCall()" src="http://192.168.1.1">`